# Cocos2d: How to perform a selector (change label) in CCSequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to change the text of label "chainsLabel" after it fades out. However, it seems I cannot do that since showChainNumber is a class method. So how can I avoid this problem?

Thanks for any advice!

Codes below:

```
+ (void)showChainNumber{
    id action = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5f]; // fading out
    id change = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector: @selector(changeText:)];
    [chainsLabel runAction:[CCSequence actions:action,change, nil]];
}

- (void)changeText:(id)sender{
    [chainsLabel setString:@""];
}
```

Comment: cocos2d which version?

Comment: Why is it a class method? It probably shouldn't be. Also you neglected to mention what the actual problem is ("it seems I cannot" is not a problem description - why does it seem to you that way? Do you get any compiler warning/error or runtime issues?).

Comment: I set it is a class method since I need to call this method in ContactListener. I did get error and the program just crushed.

Comment: I think it's the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the following code can work, just for others who have the same question:

```
    id action = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5f]; // fading out
    id change = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{[GameLayerChainMode changeText];}];
    [chainsLabel runAction:[CCSequence actions:action,change, nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first change textLabel then fade out

try this
[chainsLabel runAction:[CCSequence actions:change,action, nil]];
```